# Place 'script' before the end of BODY tags with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is the 'script' I want before the 'body' tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var vglnk = { api_url: '//api.viglink.com/api',
                key: '89dcd0a12ff35d227eaaaff82503030b' };

  (function(d, t) {
    var s = d.createElement(t); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true;
    s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? vglnk.api_url :
             '//cdn.viglink.com/api') + '/vglnk.js';
    var r = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; r.parentNode.insertBefore(s, r);
  }(document, 'script'));
</script>
```

I want this code to be where I've put "HERE"

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    Some HTML and stuff
    HERE
</body>

</html>
```

How would I go about this in jQuery?
(I'm doing this from an extension. Mainly in Chrome, but also Firefox and Internet Explorer.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5114084/139010

Comment: How would you suggest that I go about using this script on all pages?

Comment: After a test, doesn't work. Won't allow the JS to do what it needs to do on a live page.

Comment: Related: *[Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/)*

Answer (score 11):

You need the [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to do the insert on every page you want.

The code of the content script is really simple and doesn't need jQuery.

```
var code = "your script code here";
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

As it will only be called once you don't even need to define a function. You can debug the code using debugger on any web the content script is attaching (<kbd>F12</kbd>) you will see your code in the content script tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue regarding the best place to add jQuery: to the header or before the body tag? The answer is that it does not matter.

The whole page (or [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)) needs to initialize or load in order to accomplish what you are doing.

*And...*

The more information within the body, the more reliance you need to make sure the document is loaded.

The two sentences above are redundant because:

All jQuery UI, basic syntax, widgets, etc. are triggered with:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#some_id").click( function {
        More code here
    });
});`
```

The code above means that the the full HTML page (or 'document') needs to be loaded before jQuery can run, AKA initialized.

There is an order that jQuery needs to be loaded for a UI to work. The actual library needs to be first, then the UI. The library can be downloaded from jquery.com and uploaded to the designers web space or through a CDN (content display network) to save on bandwidth. Here is an example of how the order should be:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the library is the first line, and then the UI. In this case I loaded [jQuery Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile).

In conclusion, it does not matter. It is a preference mostly. More in on *[Unclear where $(document).ready goes](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/unclear-where-document-ready-goes#14737000004139019)*.

Comment: Re *"content display network"*: Don't you mean *"[content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)"*?