# getElementByClassName always returns empty array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbyclassname

I´m trying to get elements by class name out of my Google Chrome Extension, but I´m getting always an empty array back.

The classes I´m looking for do definately exist.

[image]

```
var myClasses= document.getElementsByClassName("className");
```

I´m using the Google Chrome Browser.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you show us the HTML please?

Comment: it´s actually the facebook site

Comment: What className do you want to get? Are you sure you have elements with this className? Where do you make this call? Are you sure that the page is fully loaded before calling this? If you post more code, it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: Maybe there just is no element with the class className?

Comment: Can't really help you much without some HTML to check it against I'm afraid as your javascript declaration looks fine.

Comment: Yes you can declare variables in your console @radubogdan

Comment: @radubogdan **in chrome you can**

Comment: Just tested here. [Look](http://i.imgur.com/MtX5W8B.png) @putvande
Edit: also tested in chromium. I don't have chrome sorry, but I belive you

Comment: Sry, I´m developing an google chrome extension, forget to mention that. It doesn´t work with any class

Answer (score 0):

Try this and give me the results:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); // or other html element
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 console.log(elements.className);
}
```

Comment: I´m developing a google chrome extension. As I understood, the script does only get called if the document has already loaded. I tried your code, but it doesn´t get called at all

Comment: In this case, look at this solution ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113318/in-a-chrome-extension-content-script-must-i-wait-for-document-ready-before-proc

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn´t change anything :( I´ve checked document.readyState which returns "interactive"

Comment: try the code in my updated response and say if the desired element exists

Comment: I´m getting 662 undefined