# How to execute javascript before document fully loads but after element is there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a very simple user content script for google.com, but the problem is that google's source code is lengthy. I want to execute code in javascript the instant that an element is in the document, but before the whole document has loaded.

Essentially, I wan't to change the source of an image before the rest of the page loads. I also want to modify html in a certain other div with a specific id. But again, I don't want to wait for the rest of the document to load before I start doing it.

How can I accomplish this? I am using jquery.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div

Comment: Are you able to put this script directly underneath the element? Or are you only able to put the script in a fixed location (like <head>) and need to detect when the element is available?

Comment: Could it a be a XY problem?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @EvanKennedy the latter.

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't think so because content scripts are scripts. I have to use javascript.

Comment: @yentup I didn't spot it, it is for an user script, so ya, my bad!

Comment: You can poll the DOM at frequent intervals until you find the desired div

Comment: I think I found what I'm looking for. This answer seems perfect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5114084/1313757

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**:

```
var element = $([TagName]) || document.getElementsByTagName([TagName])[[occurance]];

function doSomething() {
  // Do some magic.
}

element.addEventListener("load", doSomething, false); // Notice no brackets after the function call.
```

This adds an event listener to the element, and will wait until it has fully loaded until it runs the function (`doSomething()`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The element doesn't exist at the time the code executes.