# Chrome extension can't modify the dom of a single page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm playing around with chrome extensions. I've made a simple extension that deletes all the body content, just for learning purpose.

Works fine with almost all sites (facebook, yahoo, google) but somehow is not working here https://login.live.com/

This is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],  
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content_script.js"],   
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]  
}
```

content_script.js

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

Why the extension is not effective on that page? I'm missing something about chrome extensions or Microsoft implements some security measures?

Answer (score 1):

DOM can be added after your `document_end`-timed script executes.

Quoting Chrome docs:

> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately
>   after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and
>   frames have loaded.

So it is possible that your script executes before page's own `$(document).ready(...)` or equivalent, that still adds some content.

Comment: I think you are wrong as far as I understood, document_end and domready event are equivalent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113318/in-a-chrome-extension-content-script-must-i-wait-for-document-ready-before-proc

Comment: In any case, there's still an `onload` event that fires after all that.