# jQuery dispatchEvent won't fire on DOM load

Tags: jquery

The following works fine.  I click #testlink and it fires.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#testlink").on("click", function(event) {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('funcTest', {
            'detail': {
                test: 'stuff'
            }
        }));
    });
});
```

Now I want to do the same thing without an on.click, I want it to fire when the web page loads.  So remove the onclick.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('funcTest', {
        'detail': {
            test: 'stuff'
        }
    }));
});
```

But it doesn't work. Nothing happens.  Why?  How can I get this to fire when the page loads?

Comment: The code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/a87umsjh/ - Is the event handler for `funcTest` assigned before the `dispatchEvent` call?

Comment: yes, I think that is what is happening. funcTest is actually in a content.js which is part of a Chrome extension. its in a different sandbox.  so it must be getting assigned too late?  how would I fix that?  I'll try a setTimeout which I think is stupid.

Comment: ya, it works with a setTimeout.  Even if the timeout is super low like 2 or 10.  but as soon as I comment out the timeout it doesn't fire anymore.  I think setTimeout is ugly.  there has to be a better way to call funcTest without having to wait.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet with chrome extensions... Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113318/in-a-chrome-extension-content-script-must-i-wait-for-document-ready-before-proc) can help

Comment: Thanks, it did help.  "run_at":    "document_start" did it in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "run_at": "document_start" in the manifest for some reason makes the content script load faster.