# How do you force a content script to wait for all elements (iFrames too) to finish loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Referencing [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113318/in-a-chrome-extension-content-script-must-i-wait-for-document-ready-before-proc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)...

I have a Chrome Extension content script that I want to interact with iFrames on a specific page. I can see that my content script executes before the page finishes loading...

I tried adding document ready (which I haven't done before - I didn't think it applied to a content script) and it just executes first - before everything else.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('DOM finally loaded with iFrame...');
});
```

Here is my manifest section on content_scripts - I just added the document_idle based on the discussion in the linked question.

Is it possible to have code in a content script wait for the complete page load (including iFrames)? Or do I need to add listeners to the content script that 'see' elements I know will finally appear, then take action?

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["/dscripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "/scripts/content.js"],
        "all_frames" : true,
        "match_about_blank": true,
        "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
],
```

Comment: AFAICT there is a standard DOM event which does exactly what you want - [load](https://devdocs.io/dom_events/load) which is fired on `window`.

Comment: Yep, just tried it on nytimes.com. However it won't wait for dynamically added iframes, of course.

Comment: Thanks guys - happy to accept an answer if you want to write it. I think my mental model was a little backwards...I've ended up just listening for a user click of the element I want - which will only happen when the page is fully loaded (iFrames too)...which is what I was after all along anyway. I was trying to add listeners for an element...when really I can just use focusin and check the element activated.