# DOM manipulation not working as a firefox addon or chrome extension but works on console

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I tried to access the DOM for a webpage but I cannot do DOM maniplulation by external javascript codes, (addon or chromium extension) This code works on console page when webpage is open, but does not work as a extension. Could you please help me work this code as a extension

`document.getElementById('fb').remove()  document.getElementsByTagName('twr-comments')[0].remove() console.log("WORKED!");  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');`

Comment: Use MutationObserver or setTimeout to wait for the elements to appear.

Comment: I tried for lop 1000000 times. Never worked.

Comment: Try what I suggested. The loop is the wrong approach, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you shown will work well but I think you missed to include your .js file in content_scripts block of manifest.json

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I did include the file in manifest.json. I got an error 'cannot remove() null'

Comment: I think your code is run before render your HTML on browser in that case this will happen sure. Please refer few notes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113318/in-a-chrome-extension-content-script-must-i-wait-for-document-ready-before-proc

Comment: I indeed followed the steps to add  setTimeout(function() {
                document.QuerySelector('#comments');
            },5000); But didnt work :(. But the code is working on console. No luck

Comment: If possible can you please provide function OR few more line of code that help me to understand